# Getting the object from an array on the basis of id

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a array as follows :

```
data = [
  {
    "data": {
        "id":1,
        "vol":"0.0"
        "requiredId":100
        "details":{
            "ABC":"8.30",
            "OFG":"13.85",
            "SPG":"70.80"
        }
        
    }
  },
   {
    "data": {
        "id":2,
        "vol":"1.0",
        "requiredId":2
        "details":{
            "ABC":"3.30",
            "OFG":"15.85",
            "SPG":"70.80"
        }
        
    }
  }
]
```

I just want to get the object from this array where id is equal to requiredId. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data.find(item => item.data.id === item.data.requiredId)
```